# Does AjaxControlToolkit ToolkitScriptManager cache combined js on client?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager

Usual javascript files can be cached on a client-side if web server sets the expiration. If user has once downloaded it, it will be cached by his browser.
And what about AjaxControlToolkit ToolkitScriptManager? Are combined JS files cached on a client? How can expiration time be managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This site](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2007/06/11/script-combining-made-easy-overview-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit-s-toolkitscriptmanager.aspx) has a good explanation. It seems that the ToolScriptManager combines the JS scripts by default, using the `CombineScripts (bool)` property. 
Regarding caching:

> Of note, the cache settings of the
>   combined script file are set to the
>   same values that the individual script
>   files would have had if
>   ToolkitScriptManager weren't being
>   used and the combined script file is
>   automatically compressed according to
>   the browser's wishes.